# mutt doesn't show Maildir folders from dovecot-lda

Tags: mutt, dovecot

I use `dovecot-lda` on OpenBSD for local delivery into `Maildir`, and, by default, the inbox maildir is, effectively, located at `~/Maildir/{tmp,new,cur}`, however, all the subfolders are within `~/Maildir` itself, e.g. `~/Maildir/.Sent/{tmp,new,cur}` etc.

I use `mutt`.  When I do `c` `?`, to change folders, and navigate into `~/Maildir/`, it just shows the inbox, and doesn't seem to allow to see the folders under the inbox.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's possible to make this work by putting something like the following into `~/.muttrc`:

```
set folder=~/Maildir
set mask=".*"
```

This seems to work great until you accidentally go one level above, from `~/Maildir/` into `~/`, and then going through the list back into `~/Maildir/` seems to always bring you into the inbox, with the `c` `?` list no longer letting you see any folders beneath `~/Maildir`.  But as long as you don't go `..`, this seems to work great.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what cnst said, but with a smarter mask.  This mask shows only files that begin with a dot and are followed by a non-dot, which should show only the dove-cot mail folders and hide all of the dovecot metafiles.

```
set folder=~Maildir
set mask="^\\.[^.]"
```